# primitive to char**

Tags: c++, pointers, c-strings

I'm trying to pass a "char**" to another function (the function I want to use requires that form as the parameter), but what I have is an array of doubles.
I keep trying to find some way to convert the doubles to C-strings and either collect or concatenate them, but... I'm rolling around and not getting anywhere except compiler errors.
I'd post the code, but it's all not working junk for this.

Anyone happen to know how to take 7 double values and get a char** with them?

Comment: What does the other function actually do with the data?  That would determine how you would format it to pass it to the function.

Comment: How do you need those 7 doubles? do you want to convert 3.141 to "3.141", or does that function you're calling convert that `char**` back to a `double*`? The former somehow makes sense (but requires more than pointer conversion), the latter sounds bad. Please clarify.

Comment: Post some code. It's impossible to guess what you need from your vague description.

Comment: The actual application is reading in data from another program, and sending in parameters to an embedded Python interpreter.
I wanted to use the Python-C API and call "PySys_SetArgv" so I could access the parameters in Python code as command line arguments.

The doubles are just supposed to read and and store data that's out to a few decimal places in precision. Then get passed along to a script that's supposed to be more useful.

I ended up trying to ostringstream method Kevin suggested.
Then I used strcat() to slop an array together of C-strings. Which worked.

Comment: Next time I'm asking a question, I'll at least post some code (even if it doesn't work) so people get a better idea of what's going on. I'll also be more specific about why and what the data I care about is.
Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using C, one option is to allocate `char` buffers and call `snprintf()` to build string values from doubles, much like you would if printing a string to the console (e.g. a format string such as `"%f"` followed by the value).

If you can use C++, the `std::ostringstream` class has a similar effect (`<sstream>` header); you can `<<` numerical values into it, call `str()` to create a `std::string`, and finally call `c_str()` on the `string` object to get a `char*`.  These pointers could be put into a temporary C array to produce a `char**`.

Comment: Fantastic.
This was exactly what I needed, and fixed the problem.
I mentioned it above, but after this I just used "strcat()" to make an array of C-strings. It carried the doubles to my script just like I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand the situation:

Let declare your function f like this:

```
int f(const int n, const double* values, char** out_words);
```

First argument n is number of double numbers, values are your input double numbers, out_words is the array of C-string where you want to write the numbers.

I assume that out_words is correctly allocated with at least n pointers, each one pointing on a sufficienlty large amount of bytes to hold the numbers.

So the function body may be like this:

```
#include <string.h>
int i;
for (i=0; i<n; ++i) {
    sprintf(out_words[i], "%g", values[i]);
}
```

Comment: Change the format from "%lg" to "%g"? The OP states an input type of double, and the length modifier does not apply for this data type.